# How does loop map in php

Tags: php, laravel

I'm work laravel, so, I would like to map two loops in my view

In my controller I have the following code

```
$files = [
        [
            'group' => 'Group 1', [
                [ 'name' => 'ledstudio-v11.64d.rar', 'file' => 'ledstudio-v11.64d.rar' ],
                [ 'name' => 'ledstudio-v11.64d.rar', 'file' => 'ledstudio-v11.64d.rar' ],
            ],
        ],
        [
            'group' => 'Group 2', [
                [ 'name' => 'ledstudio-v11.64d.rar', 'file' => 'ledstudio-v11.64d.rar' ],
                [ 'name' => 'ledstudio-v11.64d.rar', 'file' => 'ledstudio-v11.64d.rar' ],
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

Group 1 and 2 for example and your subcategories
In my view I have a loop

```
 @foreach($files as $file)
        <div class="row justify-content-start">
            <div class="col-md-8">{{ $file['group'] }}</div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row"> 
            <a href="{{ url('/downloads/' . $file['file']) }}" target="_blank">
                <div class="col">
                    {{ $file['name'] }}
                </div>   
            </a> 

        </div>
    @endforeach
```

How can I to work with loop group and subgroup

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code you've posted, you should be getting the error:

> Undefined index: file (View: /path/to/view.blade.php)

This is because `$file['file']` is invalid where you've called it. `$file` is an array that looks like this:

```
array:2 [▼
  "group" => "Group 1"
  0 => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "name" => "ledstudio-v11.64d.rar"
      "file" => "ledstudio-v11.64d.rar"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "name" => "ledstudio-v11.64d.rar"
      "file" => "ledstudio-v11.64d.rar"
    ]
  ]
]
```

And at the point you call `$file['file']`, it's not available. You need to loop over the "first" element in you `$file` variable:

```
 @foreach($files as $file)
<div class="row justify-content-start">
    <div class="col-md-8">{{ $file['group'] }}</div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
@foreach($file[0] AS $subFile)
<div class="row"> 
    <a href="{{ url('/downloads/' . $subFile['file']) }}" target="_blank">
        <div class="col">
            {{ $subFile['name'] }}
        </div>   
    </a> 
</div>
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

Note: I have "first" in quotation marks, as you've got an associative array mixed with an indexed one. `$file["group"]` is available, as is `$file[0]`, but they don't reference the same index. The second loop need to be

```
@foreach($files[0] AS $subFile)
// $subFile can be renamed to something else, just an example
```

Then you use `$subFile["name"]` and `$subFile["file"]` to access the correct indices.

The above code should output:

```
<div class="row justify-content-start">
    <div class="col-md-8">Group 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row"> 
    <a href="/downloads/ledstudio-v11.64d.rar" target="_blank">
        <div class="col">
            ledstudio-v11.64d.rar
        </div>   
    </a> 
</div>
<div class="row"> 
    <a href=".../downloads/ledstudio-v11.64d.rar" target="_blank">
        <div class="col">
            ledstudio-v11.64d.rar
        </div>   
    </a> 
</div>
<div class="row justify-content-start">
    <div class="col-md-8">Group 2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row"> 
    <a href=".../downloads/ledstudio-v11.64d.rar" target="_blank">
        <div class="col">
            ledstudio-v11.64d.rar
        </div>   
    </a> 
</div>
<div class="row"> 
    <a href=".../downloads/ledstudio-v11.64d.rar" target="_blank">
        <div class="col">
            ledstudio-v11.64d.rar
        </div>   
    </a> 
</div>
```

Comment: its perfect friend, resolve my problem thanks, I did separeted in group and subgroup,